# Unable to clear selected checkbox label in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
uncheck: function(checkedName) {
    this.checkedNames = this.checkedNames.filter(name => name !== checkedName);
  },
  uncheckall: function(event) {
    this.checkedNames = [];
  },

  checkedInput(event) {
    if (this.checkedNames.includes(event.target.value)) {
      this.uncheck(event.target.value)
    } else {
      this.checkedNames.push(event.target.value)
    }
  },
```

```html
<div class="checkbox-alignment-form-filter">
  <input type="checkbox" id="H11" class="vh-product" value="1" v-model="checkboxes[0]"  @click="checkedInput" />
  <label class="productlist-specific" for="HR1">H1</label
                >
              </div>
              <div class="checkbox-alignment-form-filter2">
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  id="E0A"
                  class="vh-product"
                  v-model="checkboxes[1]"
                  value="E0A"
                  @click="checkedInput"
                />
                <label class="productlist-specific" for="E0A">E0A</label>
</div>

</div>


<li @mouseover="mouseOver" @mouseleave="mouseOut" @click="uncheck(checkedName)" class="filtersapplied-productlist2" v-for="checkedName in checkedNames" :key="checkedName">
  {{ checkedName }}
  <span class="filtertag-plp" v-show="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</span
            >
          </li>
          <li
            class="filtersapplied-productlist4"
            @mouseover="mouseOver"
            @mouseleave="mouseOut"
            @click="uncheckall"
            v-show="checkedNames != ''"
          >
            CLEAR ALL
          </li>
```

Unable to close the checkbox selected label, I am able to display the selected checkbox label but when trying to clear the checkbox with clear all option unable to unselect the checkboxes.

I am not sure what is the wrong in my code in the method checkedInput (or) in the li i need to pass specific id in order to clear.

This is the reference code i have taken, But with some modifications i tried https://jsfiddle.net/8xom729c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to bind the `v-model` to an index of the `checkboxes` array.

Try changing it from

```
v-model="checkboxes[0]" // also checkboxes[1], checkboxes[2], etc
```

to

```
v-model="checkboxes"
```

Vue automatically handles binding of checkboxes as [described in the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox)

If you do what you're doing, the array becomes filled with `undefined/true` instead of the value of the checkboxes.

This can lead to conflicts and issues with resetting their state.